# insert image with value of datatools

Tags: macros

Happy new year all,

Last topic: [rotate text in posterbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484750/rotate-text-in-posterbox)

Now, i want insert image with newcommand statement/macros:

Position view: in below=5mm of BOX

if No = A/B/C => view image example A/B/C

else view blank/nothing in this position

Thank advance and happy new year 2020

My minimal coding:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.tex}
No,TextX,TextY,TextZ,TextW
1,x1,y1,z1,w1
B,,y2,z2,w2
3,,y3,w3,
A,,,,w4
5,x5,y5,,
6,,y6,z6,w6
A,x7,y7,z7,w7
8,x8,,z8,w8
9,x9,,z9,w9
C,x10,y10,z10,w10
11,,y11,z11,w11
A,,y12,,
13,,,z13,w13
B,x14,,z14,w14
15,x15,y15,,w15
C,x16,y16,z16,w16
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{enumitem, setspace}
\tcbset{colframe=blue!75!black,colback=white}

\DTLloaddb{file}{\jobname.tex}


\newcommand{\No}[1]{%
\if
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a} 
\else
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b} 
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*{file}% Database
{\No=No,\TextX=TextX,\TextY=TextY,\TextZ=TextZ,\TextW=TextW}
{%
\begin{tcbposter}[
poster = {
columns=1,
rows=1,
spacing=3mm,
height=14cm,
width=12cm,
},
]

 \posterbox[
  colframe = red,
  width=6cm, height= 6cm
  ]{name=BOX,column=1}{insert image with condition}
  \node[font=\sffamily\Large,rotate=0,below=5mm of TCBPOSTER@BOX]  {\No};
\end{tcbposter}
\newpage
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happy New Year!

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{pleasedonotusefilenamehere.tex}
No,TextX,TextY,TextZ,TextW
1,x1,y1,z1,w1
B,,y2,z2,w2
3,,y3,w3,
A,,,,w4
5,x5,y5,,
6,,y6,z6,w6
A,x7,y7,z7,w7
8,x8,,z8,w8
9,x9,,z9,w9
C,x10,y10,z10,w10
11,,y11,z11,w11
A,,y12,,
13,,,z13,w13
B,x14,,z14,w14
15,x15,y15,,w15
C,x16,y16,z16,w16
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{poster}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{enumitem, setspace}
\tcbset{colframe=blue!75!black,colback=white}

\DTLloaddb{file}{pleasedonotusefilenamehere.tex}


\newcommand{\NoCond}[1]{%
\begingroup
\edef\myA{A}%
\edef\myB{B}%
\edef\myC{C}%
\ifx#1\myA
 \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a} 
\else
 \ifx#1\myB
  \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b} 
 \else
  \ifx#1\myC
   \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c} 
  \else
  \fi
 \fi  
\fi
\endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*{file}% Database
{\No=No,\TextX=TextX,\TextY=TextY,\TextZ=TextZ,\TextW=TextW}
{%
\begin{tcbposter}[
poster = {
columns=1,
rows=1,
spacing=3mm,
height=14cm,
width=12cm,
},
]

 \posterbox[
  colframe = red,
  width=6cm, height= 6cm
  ]{name=BOX,column=1}{\NoCond{\No}}
  \node[font=\sffamily\Large,rotate=0,below=5mm of TCBPOSTER@BOX]  {\No};
\end{tcbposter}
\newpage
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. Please do not use `\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.tex}`, the few remaining non-overleaf users will appreciate it if their main file does not get overwritten.